Restriction of solution operator of a elliptical equation in $\mathbb{R}^N$
For a given $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, we know by Riez Representation Theorem that there exists a unique $B(u) \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \nabla B(u) \nabla \varphi + B(u) \varphi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}  u \varphi, \quad \forall \varphi \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N).
$$
If $u(x) = 0$ for $x \in A$, is it true that $B(u)(x) = 0$ for $x \in A$?
What I really need: In this  paper (page 718)it is used the fallowing fact: If $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is a weak solution of
$$
-\Delta u + B(u) = f(u), \mathbb{R}^N,
$$
where $f(s) = 0$ if $s \leq 0$, then
$$
\int_{A} B(u^+) u^- = 0, \quad  \text{ for }A := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : u \leq 0\}.
$$
which I don't know how to prove. If we take $u^-$ as a test function we obtain
$$
-\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u^-|^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} B(u)u^- = 0.
$$
The the linearity of $B$ and using $u = u^+ - u^-$ yields
$$
-\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u^-|^2 - \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} B(u^-)u^- + \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} B(u^+)u^- = 0.
$$
In the calculus of the paper I think it is used
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} B(u^+)(x)u^-(x) dx = 0,
$$
to conclude that
$$
-\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u^-|^2 - \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} B(u^-)u^- = 0,
$$
but I don't know how to deal with it.

One idea would be to test the weak formulation with $u^-$.

I have tried this. I just wrote my attempt.

$B(u^-)\le0$ so that the last line implies $\nabla u^-=0$. No idea how to prove $\int_{\mathbb R^N} B(u^-)u^+=0$.

If $\nabla u^-=0$ and $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ then $u^{-}\equiv 0$, and so $B(u^{-})=0$. By duality this implies the vanishing of the integral. On the other hand this seems to be much stronger than what is being asked; @LucasLinhares do you know if at any point the authors prove $u\geq 0$? (this is what $u^-=0$ is)

Yes, the authors want to prove that $u^- =0$, but they use in the calculos what I asked.
